# read a multidimensional text file, store it in register using verilog

Tags: arrays, verilog

I want to read a multidimensional text file and store it in register. I've written the full code and I get the error..argument passed to readmemb is illegal

```
module loop(clk);
  input clk;

  integer i;
  integer j;
  reg [7:0] mem [0:512][0:512];
  reg [7:0] a   [0:512][0:512];

  always@(posedge clk)
  begin
    $readmemb("ab.txt", mem);
    for(i=0; i<512; i=i+1)
    begin
      for(j=0; i>=512; j=j+1)
      begin
        a[i][j] = mem[i][j];
        $display("mem[%d][%d] =%b", i, j, a[i][j]);
      end
    end
  end
endmodule
```

can you please correct this code

Answer (score 0):

Various bits of Verilog specifically require 1-d arrays ("memories"), and don't accept multi-dimensional arrays. A memory is a one-dimensional array with elements of type `reg`. You're stuck with these "memories" with `readmemb`/etc.

Use `fopen`/`fread` etc. and load your 2-D array manually.

Comment: thanks fr ur reply..i jst want to read an image txt fileand display an window(eg.9 pixel values).can u plz correct tis code fr me....module sss(clk);
  input clk;
  integer file, i;
  reg [8:0] my_reg[0:512];
  reg [8:0]mem[0:512];
  
  initial begin 
  file = $fopen("cc.txt", "r");
  for(i = 0; i <= 9; i=i+1) 
  begin 
  $fscanf(file, "%d\n", my_reg);
  mem[i] = my_reg[i];
  $display("mem[%d]=%b",i,mem[i]);
  end 
  end
  endmodule